# MAMP For Mac could not connect to hosted Sql Server

Tags: php, sql-server, macos, mamp

I'm Using MAMP for Mac, and I'm trying to connect to my SQL hosted online, but is not connecting for some reason, I try to use another alternative's software, like AMMPs and it seems to work fine, but I'm not to familiar with this software and I like better MAMP, has anyone run into this problem too? thanks in advance.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem.   I wonder if the latest release of mamp has a bug.

Comment: I try using the previous version 2.2 but I couldn't even get the apache server running..